# Not able to import cx_Oracle in python "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found."

Tags: oracle, python-2.7, cx-oracle

It's been two days I am trying to work with cx_Oracle. I want to connect to oracle from python. But I am getting "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found." error. I have already gone through many posts and tried the things suggested on them, but nothing helped me.

I checked the versions of Windows, Python, Oracle client as suggested on many posts but all of them looks good to me.

Python veriosn 2.7: 64 bit

Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32

Windows 7: 64 bit

Oracle client is 11.2.0: 64 bit

I ran Sqlplus and checked task manager to confirm that. As I have both 32 and 64 bit client installed on my system, but 64 bit is set in PATH variable.

Please help me to sort out this problem. Do let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: Can you post the full error message/stack? Does %ORACLE_HOME% point to the right Oracle client when running the Python program, does it have permissions to the libraries?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sort it out. I had installed the incorrect version of cx_Oracle previously. It was for 12c oracle client. I installed 11g version later and it started working for me.

Note: There is no need to set ORACLE_HOME environment variable.

Oracle client, Python, Windows OS all of them must be of same architecture. Either 32 or 64 bit.